# Overlaying Nav bar on background image

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm building a website in a strange way,

The designer for the site has created a background image with the title and buttons for the nav bar built INTO the image, and would like me to make them clickable using HTML.

This isn't actually a problem when I can build it for a specific resolution, as below. [Nav bar overlaying an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xini9.png)

However, when the resolution of the website changes, the position of the nav bar shifts to a different area, making it useless.

[nav bar position changes, making it useless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ABoB.png)

I need a way to make my nav bar align and scale itself to the background image.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>
        Patrick Walsh 3D
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.html">
            <div id="homeButton">
                <!--This is an empty div, used to define a portion of the screen that is clickable-->
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="resume.html">
            <div id="resumeButton">
                <!--This is an empty div, used to define a portion of the screen that is clickable-->
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="tutorial.html">
            <div id="tutorialButton">
                <!--This is an empty div, used to define a portion of the screen that is clickable-->
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="contact.html">
            <div id="contactButton">
                <!--This is an empty div, used to define a portion of the screen that is clickable-->
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

#buffer{}


body{
    background-image:url(Background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#nav{
    background-color:white;
    opacity:.5;
    width:58%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:21%;
}

#nav a{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}

/*Divs that overlay buttons on background image*/
#homeButton{
    background-color:green;
    width:13%;
    height:80%;
    position: absolute;
    left:1%;
    top:2px;
}

#resumeButton{
    background-color:red;
    width:16%;
    height:80%;
    position: absolute;
    left:26%;
    top:2px;
}

#tutorialButton{
    background-color:blue;
    width:17%;
    height:80%;
    position: absolute;
    left:52%;
    top:2px;
}

#contactButton{
    background-color:orange;
    width:17%;
    height:80%;
    position: absolute;
    left:78%;
    top:2px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way. The buttons should not be part of the image but separate elements on top of it. I'd suggest you go back to the *so called* designer and get a new background image. Any competent designer **should know this**.

Comment: What visual effect justifies having the menu links part of the background image? Just have the dinosaur as a body background, "logo" as PNG and the menu should be a container with either RGBA color for transparency or a PNG background and the links live as text or images if you really want gradient text.. you may check this too https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this might help put Maybe instead of having the image as an background.. You can use the  tag??
This will create a clickable mapped image.
http://www.image-maps.com/
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks. My current approach is to tell the designer not to be an idiot and re-make the background image properly.

Comment: That worked perfectly, and I learned a new tag. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem.. I use this all the time.. A very great tag indeed.

Comment: Image maps? Wow, why do you have to complicate things? what would you do if you want to add or remove menu items? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the position of the bar to fixed or a pixel position that that is fixed ops from the top.

Comment: I have, the page has to be scrollable, so fixed isn't possible, and having a pixel positioning only makes the problem worse, as the background image will scale to suit the device resolution without the nav bar making the same change.